# Aligning UILabel text after rotating with auto-layout constraints

Tags: swift, autolayout, uilabel, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to get a line of text to match up on what when rotated, is the top of the `UILabel`. Currently, within each `UICollectionViewCell` I am setting rotating the label 180 degrees. The label's text aligned left however as shown in the attached image this shouldn't make any difference.

I am unable to set the text before performing this due to `UICollectionViewController` dequeuing the cell, so at this point in the constructor the label's text isn't set, however, I've tested setting it to "AAA" beforehand and that had no effect.

```swift
label.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi / 2)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor),
    label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -15)])
```

The results:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, first thing to understand here is that although you're rotating the label, the transform does not change the frame - meaning, your bottom constraint is still applied to what was the bottom before the rotation.

A quick fix for this would be to add a width constraint to each of your labels, then set the text alignment to .right.

I imagine you could also make the same result by using a vertical stackView with labels aligned right, then rotating the stackView.

Anything else, and you'd probably have to override the draw method and subclass the UILabel.

Comment: Thanks, that worked great! Adding the width by just adding left and right constraint allowed me to align them with the text alignment.